# Не работает REST API на сервере

Tags: linux, django, vue.js, nginx, rest

Сервер на digitalocean Ubuntu

Задеплоил django проект в /root//FEFUToogesher/Back

config/settins.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import djoser
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'Optional default value')

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.userProfile'


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'api',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djoser',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]



CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://167.71.180.222:8002',
                        'http://167.71.180.222:80',
                        'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
                        'http://localhost:8080',]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'full_db'
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

# Heroku: Update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../staticfiles'))

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
```

api(мое django приложение)/urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import EventViewSet, CustomAuthToken
from django.urls import include, path

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'events', EventViewSet,basename='event')



urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
    path("token/", CustomAuthToken.as_view(), name='token'),
]
```

config/wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Поднял gunicorn как daemon /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/FEFUTogether/Back
ExecStart=/root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/gunicorn  --access-logfile - --workers 5 --bind '127.0.0.1:8000' config.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Поднял Nginx /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
listen 8002 default_server;
listen [::]:8002 default_server;

server_name _;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /staticfilse/ {
        root /root/FEFUTogether/Back;
        }


location / { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://167.71.180.222:8080;
        }
}
```

Задеплоил VueApp /var/www/html/vue/Front

/var/www/html/vue/Front/src/api/common.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
export const HTTP = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://167.71.180.222:8002/api'
})
```

/var/www/html/vue/Front/src/api/elements.js

```
import { HTTP } from './common'


export const Organisations = {
    async post (config) {
        return HTTP.post('/events/', config).then(response => {
            return response.data
        })
    },
    async delete (organisation) {
        return HTTP.delete(`/events/${organisation.id}/`)
    },
    async put (organisation) {
        return HTTP.delete(`/events/${organisation.id}/`)
    },
    async get (organisation) {
        return HTTP.get(`/events/${organisation.id}/`)
    },
    async list () {
        return HTTP.get(`/events/`).then(response => {
            return response.data
        })
    },
    async patch (organisation) {
        return HTTP.patch(`/events/${organisation.id}/`)
    },
}
```

Поднял Nginx /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
        listen 8080 default_server;
        listen [::]:8080 default_server;
        root /var/www/html/vue/Front/dist;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _1;
        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Статус Nginx

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-12-30 03:45:38 UTC; 7s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 68996 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 69012 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 69013 (nginx)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 2344)
     Memory: 3.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─69013 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             ├─69014 nginx: worker process
             └─69015 nginx: worker process

Dec 30 03:45:38 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Dec 30 03:45:38 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Статус gunicorn

```
 gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-12-30 03:45:31 UTC; 1min 48s ago
   Main PID: 68965 (gunicorn)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 2344)
     Memory: 165.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
             ├─68965 /root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/python /root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 5 --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 config.wsgi:application
             ├─68984 /root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/python /root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 5 --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 config.wsgi:application
             ├─68985 /root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/python /root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 5 --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 config.wsgi:application
             ├─68986 /root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/python /root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 5 --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 config.wsgi:application
             ├─68987 /root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/python /root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 5 --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 config.wsgi:application
             └─68988 /root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/python /root/FEFUTogether/Back/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 5 --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 config.wsgi:application

Dec 30 03:45:31 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Dec 30 03:45:31 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[68965]: [2020-12-30 03:45:31 +0000] [68965] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
Dec 30 03:45:31 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[68965]: [2020-12-30 03:45:31 +0000] [68965] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (68965)
Dec 30 03:45:31 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[68965]: [2020-12-30 03:45:31 +0000] [68965] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Dec 30 03:45:31 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[68984]: [2020-12-30 03:45:31 +0000] [68984] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 68984
Dec 30 03:45:31 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[68985]: [2020-12-30 03:45:31 +0000] [68985] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 68985
Dec 30 03:45:31 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[68986]: [2020-12-30 03:45:31 +0000] [68986] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 68986
Dec 30 03:45:31 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[68987]: [2020-12-30 03:45:31 +0000] [68987] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 68987
Dec 30 03:45:31 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[68988]: [2020-12-30 03:45:31 +0000] [68988] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 68988
```

Проблема в том, что по отдельности и django и Vue работают, они также работают одновременно, пока не идут запросы с Vue на REST API, но как только приходит ответ на запрос, Vue перестает работать !!!ПОЛНОСТЬЮ!!!

Я перехожу в браузере по своему ip на 8080 порт, страница частично прогружается, и на этом заканчивается, самое странное, что я даже не могу проинспектировать страницу, просто не работает F12 ничего не работает, я уже 2 дня экспериментирую с конфигурациями всего, что можно, но безуспешно

Если я добавляю в CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
'http://167.71.180.222:8080'

Тогда я получаю в консоли следующее

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://167.71.180.222:8002/api/events/' from origin 'http://167.71.180.222:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://167.71.180.222:8080, http://167.71.180.222:8080', but only one is allowed.
vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 Error: Network Error
    at t.exports (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d.onerror (xhr.js:84)
oe @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1888
:8002/api/events/:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

, что вполне логично, но, если я убираю CORE заголовок в конфигурации Nginx, Vue также перестает работать

P.S. Этот же код прекрасно работал на heroku
P.S.2 Прикладываю сами конфиги Nginx

```
user root;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml applicatio>

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: если не отрабатывает F12, то у Вас переполнен стек вызовов. это происходит при первых попытках обратиться к бэку с фронта?

Comment: Да, именно так, как только я переключаю порт для выполнение fetch на порт с REST API, все перестает работать @user:371819

Comment: посмотрите логи, nginx, gunicorn, django. Там наверное и есть ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: _/root_ серьёзно?!

Comment: Извините, впервые работал что с Linux, что с deploy в принципе @0andriy

Comment: Ничего страшного, просто на будущее лучше вообще запретить логины в root. (Только через `sudo` с включенным аудитом кто и что делал) И понятное дело не трогать в его домашнем каталоге ничего руками.